# My program showed me the segmentation failed and it didn't show the input data. Anybody knows how to solve it?

Tags: c

When I tried to run the program, it still work ( For input ), but then for printData function didn't work. It didn't show me the data that I have input before. Still the same.. I didn't know where is my fault, because usually I make the program like this and it worked perfectly. Please help me.. Thank you very much

### My program :-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
    int ID;
        char name;
        char class;
        int score1;
        int score2;
}std[100];

void addData(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Data number %d\n",i+1);
            printf("ID : ");scanf("%d",std[i].ID);
            printf("Name : ");scanf("%s",std[i].name);
            printf("Class : ");scanf("%s",std[i].class);
            printf("Score 1 : ");scanf("%d",std[i].score1);
            printf("Score 2 : ");scanf("%d",std[i].score2);
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void printData(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Data number %d\n",i+1);
        printf("ID : %d",std[i].ID);
        printf("Name : %s",std[i].name);
        printf("Class : %s",std[i].class);
        printf("Score 1 : %d",std[i].score1);
        printf("Score 2 : %d",std[i].score2);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    addData();
    printf("Print Data\n");
    printData();
    return 0;
}
```

[You can check online in here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkjsHAsL_)

Comment: is this the complete program ? because I can't see you declaring array `std[]` anywhere.

Comment: @Arsenic I've edited it.. I'm sorry.. And thank you for fixing my program before

Comment: You are scanffing strings into single char vars.

Comment: Your `name` and `class` members of the struct are just one character. You probably get more than one character as input, and that's most likely your problem. Also, scanf specifier for character is `%c` and not `%s`, though you should avoid using scanf like that.

Comment: I am surprised that this compiles wirhout a fatal error, never mind a warning:(

Comment: ..and missing '&' address operators for the scanf's.  C functions cannot mutate arguments because they are copied into parameters by value.

Comment: The segmentation didn't fail. Your program did. Segmentation is used to protect memory from invalid usage. I'd say it was pretty successful at that. To solve a problem, your first step should be to identify the problem. If you get an error you don't understand, find out what it means before trying to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation faults are due to an invalid dereference of a pointer. Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
    int ID;
        char name;
        char class;
        int score1;
        int score2;
}std[100];

void addData(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Data number %d\n",i+1);
            printf("ID : ");scanf("%d",&std[i].ID);
            printf("Name : ");scanf("%s",&std[i].name);
            printf("Class : ");scanf("%s",&std[i].class);
            printf("Score 1 : ");scanf("%d",&std[i].score1);
            printf("Score 2 : ");scanf("%d",&std[i].score2);
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void printData(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Data number %d\n",i+1);
        printf("ID : %d",std[i].ID);
        printf("Name : %s",std[i].name);
        printf("Class : %s",std[i].class);
        printf("Score 1 : %d",std[i].score1);
        printf("Score 2 : %d",std[i].score2);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    addData();
    printf("Print Data\n");
    printData();
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, `scanf()` needs the address of the variable that it will put the input in.

Comment: Instead of the rampant `std[i]` repetition, consider using a pointer.